# Update Query for SQL Sever VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need help about update I have two columns in table, `ID` and `Price`. I need when I have like 10 in my column `Price` and I type like 12 then message box show (you do not have enough amount in price column

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1"
cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Table_9 SET ID = @ID,Price =CAST((CAST(Price AS INT)-" & TextBox1.Text & ") AS VARCHAR(10)) WHERE ID = @ID")

cn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()

MessageBox.Show("success")
```

Comment: *Don't* construct queries by concatenating strings. Use parameterized queries, it's actually *easier*, faster and safer. In this particular case concatenation is pointless. You *already* started with parameters

Comment: Why is the @ID parameter a single character instead of eg an int? Why is `Price` cast to a string to, instead of passing it as an integer, or decimal?. And finally, what is the query supposed to do? What it does now is *wipe out all IDs* and replace them with 1

Comment: The query should be `Update ThatTable Set Price=Price-@price where ID=@ID`, with `@ID` and `@price` having types that actually match the fields. Instead of trying to pass a string for price, *parse* it in advance, eg with `int.Parse` or `decimal.Parse` and use the parsed number as a parameter value

Comment: i have - price from my price column

Comment: Kindly confirm that you want to update price column against that ID or you want to just check enough price against that ID in Table_9 table.

Comment: @Sattar5 this doesn't explain anything. `price` isn't a type and the query itself doesn't make sense. It will overwrite *all* IDs in the table with the value `1`

Comment: yes I have two columns in table, ID and Price. I need when I have like 10 in my column Price and I type like 12 in textbox then message box show (you do not have enough amount in price column

Comment: dear i am minus the amount from column Price through my textbox if i type 15 in my textbox and the aviail price will 10 then message box show you do not have enough amount in column price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim Scmd As New SqlCommand

Scmd.Connection = cn
Scmd.CommandText = ("SELECT Price  FROM Table_9  WHERE ID = @ID")
Smd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1"
cn.Open()
Dim DBPrice As Integer = Smd.ExecuteScalar()

IF(DBPrice >Cint( TextBox1.Text)) Then
   cmd.Connection = cn
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "1"
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
   cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Table_9 SET ID = @ID,Price =CAST((CAST(Price AS INT)-@Price) AS VARCHAR(10)) WHERE ID = @ID")
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()   
   MessageBox.Show("success")
Else
   MessageBox.Show("you do not have enough amount in price column")
End If
cn.Close()
```

Comment: i got error in this two lines     Integer DBPrice = Scmd.ExecuteScalar()

        If (DBPrice > TextBox1.Text) Then

Comment: now error showing in this line   Integer DBPrice = Scmd.ExecuteScalar()

Comment: you check the code it not working showing error before run the program

Comment: Correct Working 100%

Answer (score -1):

Please use syntax like following.

Example as below :

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Student 
SET Address = @add, City = @cit Where FirstName = @fn and LastName = @add";
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is using both parameters and concatenation with a query that overwrites the entire table